# questions regarding modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

1. Let $f$ be modular of level $p^nN$, $(p,n) = 1$, $p > 2$ with character $\chi\psi\eta$, where $\chi$ has conductor dividing $N$, $\psi$ conductor power of $p$ and order power of $p$, and $\eta$ conductor $p$ and order dividing $p-1$. Since $p$ is odd, one can write $\psi = \xi^{-2}$. (i) Why is the character of  $f \otimes \xi$ equal to $\chi\eta$; (ii) why is the reduction mod $p$ of this equal to the reduction of $f$; (iii) why is for $r \gg n$ $f \otimes \xi$ modular with respect to $\Gamma_0(p^r) \cap \Gamma_1(pN)$? Can this be proven using the converse theorem?

2.a Why is the twisted Eisenstein series $G = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{d \mid n}\eta^{-1}(d)d^{i-1}q^n$ of Nebentypus $\eta^{-1}$ with respect to $\Gamma_0(p)$?

2.b Why is $fG$ modular with respect to $\Gamma_0(p^r) \cap \Gamma_1(N)$, wenn $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(p^r) \cap\ \Gamma_1(pN), \chi\eta)$ ist?

(The article is here: math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/motives.pdf )

Comment: Most of these questions would be answered by a solid overview article or basic textbook on the theory of modular forms.  There are lots of these.  I recall being fond of Miyake's book ("Modular Forms") when I first learned about this stuff, for example (though I don't know if he covers twisting).  The article by Diamond and Im ("Modular forms and modular curves") does a pretty impressive job in a small space, but I think that this is best read after something a little slower paced.

I suggest spending some time with a couple of reference like this first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

William Stein has answered your question (i).  As for your question (ii), since $\xi$ has $p$-power order, and since any $p$-power root of unity is congruent to $1$ modulo the unique prime ideal lying over $p$ in $\mathbb Q$ adjoin the $p$-power roots of unity, we see
that $f\otimes \xi$ is congruent to $f$ modulo any prime ideal lying over $p$ in the
field of definition of $f$ adjoin the $p$-power roots of unity.

Finally, you have already noted in (i) that the character of $f\otimes \xi$ is just
$\chi\eta$.  Since the conductor of $\xi$ divides $N$ and the conductor of $\eta$ divides $p$,
we see that the conductor of $\chi\eta$ divides $p N$.  This gives (iii).  (Note that (iii)
is simply a statement about the conductor of the character of $f\otimes \xi$: In general, a modular form $g$ of level $C$ is modular on $\Gamma_0(C)\cap \Gamma_1(D)$, rather than just $\Gamma_1(C)$, for some integer $D$ dividing $C$, 
if the character of $g$, a priori a character of $(\mathbb Z/C)^{\times}$, actually
factors through $(\mathbb Z/D)^{\times}$.  In your particular case, $f$ has conductor a power of $p$ times $N$, and $\xi$ has conductor a power of $p$, so $f\otimes \xi$ has 
conductor a power of $p$ times $N$.  The conductor of its character divide $p N$, as
already noted, and so (iii) follows.)

Answer (score 9):

This question (at least when I read it right now) seems loaded with typos...  In any case, regarding (i) it's a general fact that if $f$ is a modular form with character $\varepsilon$ and $\chi$ is any Dirichlet character, then $f \otimes \chi$ is a modular forms with character $\varepsilon \cdot \chi^2$.  See Proposition 3.64 of Shimura's book *Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions*.  This answers your question (i).

I'm curious what motivated this question.  It seems like perhaps the person asking it was reading a paper, and wanted to check some claims in the paper, but didn't know how.  If so, what paper was it?

Comment: The article is here: http://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/motives.pdf page 5.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question (2.a), I believe that your 'twisted' Eisenstein series is a special case of a very classical (and well known) construction.

Let $k\geq 2$. Suppose that you have two primitive Dirichlet characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ modulo $N_1$ and $N_2$ respectively (if $k=2$ then suppose also that both characters are not trivial). We construct a modular form as follows.

Set $$a_0=- L(0,\chi_1)L(1-k,\chi_2).$$

For $n>0$ define $$a_n = \sum_{d\mid n} \chi_1(\frac{n}{d})\chi_2(d) d^{k-1}.$$

Its worth noting that $$L(s,\chi_1)L(1+s-k, \chi_2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}.$$

**Theorem**: Let $F_{\chi_1,\chi_2}=\sum a_n q^n$. Then $F_{\chi_1,\chi_2}\in M_k(N_1N_2,\chi_1\chi_2)$. In fact, $F_{\chi_1,\chi_2}$ is an Eisenstein series.

Your question follows from taking $\chi_1=1$ and $\chi_2=\eta^{-1}$.

As I said, this is a very classical construction and should be in any book introductory text (e.g. Miyake, Diamond and Shurman, Shimura).